# Trying to compile GWT code using Sublime Text 2 on a MBP

Tags: gwt, sublimetext2

I am developing a small GWT based web application and using Sublime Text 2 as my editor for GWT code. I have added the following jar in my PATH:

gwt-2.5.0/gwt-user.jar

Still when I build the entry point java file, Sublime Text complains that it cannot see any of the GWT packages.

I am using the gwt-user.jar in the path since that is what I saw Eclipse requires to build the file. Is it possible to compile GWT code using ST or should I default to Eclipse?

Comment: include `gwt-dev.jar` as well for the development phase build. plus, AFAIK, Sublime is not an IDE, thus not capable of compiling source code (GWT or not). i assume you're using a build tool regardless.

Comment: I do not exactly understand the reason for your use of Sublime Text 2 with GWT. can you do line by line debug as in eclipse with Sublime Text 2?

Comment: Eliran, I am using the Build functionality which is available in Sublime Text to build it.

Comment: Hi SSR, I know its counter intuitive but I like developing with light weight editors. Sublime Text 2 does not provide line by line debug.